# Image moves on mouseover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve rollover of image on mouseover. i have a div having the background image.on mouseover on that div the background image will rollover. But the issue i'm facing is that when the image rollsover,the image is moving with that. for example when i mouseover the div, the image which is actually height of 217px will become 157px; while reducing the height of the div, the image is actually moving little upside, i don't want the image to move upside while the rollover effect. how can i avoid this.

i tried with `background-position:fixed` property, but this kinda giving the parallax effect

here's what i have done.

```css
    .img-holder{
     height:217px;
     width:543px;
     background:#dedede;
     position:relative;
    
    }
    .bg-img{
     position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        content: "";
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.06, 1);
        transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.06, 1);
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -300px 100px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow: inset 0px -300px 100px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    
    
    .bg-img:hover{
     height:157px;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) !important;
        transform: scale(1.0) !important;
    }
```

```html
<div class="img-holder">
     <div class="bg-img" style="background-image:url('https://netcomtech.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Workspace.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
```

Actual effect i'm trying to achieve is that
when mouseover the div should reduce its height, but the background-image of that div should not move with it.

Comment: What effect want you actually to achive? … what should the image do, what should the parent do?

Comment: Like that https://jsfiddle.net/ech964f7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the background image and the hover effect for the "container" div instead will help you get the specific effect, but as other answers have mentioned, there are generally better ways to do it. :)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqNKKN

```css
.img-holder{
    height:217px;
    width:543px;
    background:#dedede;
    position:relative;

    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.06, 1);
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.06, 1);
  background-image: url('https://netcomtech.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Workspace.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.bg-img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -300px 100px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0px -300px 100px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


.img-holder:hover{
    height:157px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) !important;
    transform: scale(1.0) !important;
}
```

Comment: if you notice that the image moves little upside while the div reduces height, thats what i want to avoid.

Comment: Ah okay. Updated the codepen and will update the code block above.

Comment: Don't want to be rude or anything but thats just very messy code for achieving that effect. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzZVrQ

Comment: Not rude at all, and I understand. But I figured not editing the code that didn't fix the problem was the appropriate way to go, since they wouldn't know WHAT fixed their issue if the whole thing was rewritten from under them.

Comment: Yeah in the original code are several very bad things like attributes that are unnecessary or just wrong like scale or content … It seems like Chandan has not much experience in CSS so it might help to show him  and others whats actually wrong or how to do it right.

Comment: I think that's a valid approach. :) Just not what I did at the time.

Answer (score 2):

Use `background-position: 100% 100%;` instead `center center`

```css
.img-holder{
    height:217px;
    width:543px;
    background:#dedede;
    position:relative;

}
.bg-img{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    content: "";
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.06, 1);
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0, 0.06, 1);
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -300px 100px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0px -300px 100px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


.bg-img:hover{
    height:157px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) !important;
    transform: scale(1.0) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-holder">
    <div class="bg-img" style="background-image:url('https://netcomtech.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Workspace.jpg');"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: If that is the desired effect (cant imagine that) i recommend using .img-holder:hover .bg-img to prevent quirky behaviours when entering from the bottom of the container ;)

Comment: I tried that as well, but its not working,  i have updated the OP of the actual effect i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You mean that you see all image even the `height` is less

Comment: what i mean is if you notice that the image moves little upside while the div reduces height, thats what i want to avoid..

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqNKKN